# KDE notification popup appears only when I attach a second screen

Tags: kde, notification, kde4

I use kde 4.13.3.  I dont see a popup for notifications when I use only one screen but once I attach a second screen.

How could I move the popup to be shown in the main screen whether I attached a second screen or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it by attaching a second screen than drag notification popup by mouse and move it to the main screen.

When detaching the second screen, the popup will always appear in the main screen.